# Closing the default camera in Blackberry programatically after taking a picture

Tags: blackberry, java-me, camera

In my application, Im using the default blackberry camera player to capture images using this..  - Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_CAMERA, new CameraArguments(CameraArguments.ARG_CAMERA_APP));

But after capturing the image, the user has to click the back button inorder to navigate to the next screen. Is there any option to close the player automatically, after capturing the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Unable-to-close-camera-using-EventInjector-for-touch-screen/m-p/785247#M143879). The idea is to use `EventInjector` to simulate two Escape button presses while being in the Camera app. Note this requires a permission (PERMISSION_INPUT_SIMULATION) from your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot...Arhimed . It did the trick, but will that cause any security issues?

Comment: You just have no other way to close the Camera app automatically. So if some of your customers are frightened with this permission, then they will have to close the app manually.