# Closing the Camera Application from a T/P Application

Tags: java, blackberry, camera, exit

My Problem... I have accessed the Camera App from my third party app , I then take a picture. then I go to the Menu and I have added in a menuitem  (MENUITEM_CAMERA_PREVIEW) . My menu item must perform a function and once it has I want my app to close the camera and open the previose screen before the Camera app was opened.

I am  facing the same problems as this thread :
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-exit-camera-app-properly/m-p/1924127#M209092

Can someone please tell me they understand the solution, if not and you maybe know the solution your help would be much appreciated.

I have seen these post:
[Closing the default camera in Blackberry programatically after taking a picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949292/closing-the-default-camera-in-blackberry-programatically-after-taking-a-picture)

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Unable-to-close-camera-using-EventInjector-for-touch-screen/m-p/785247#M143879

[How to exit a blackberry application from another application programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978317/how-to-exit-a-blackberry-application-from-another-application-programatically)

But I am not sure what I am supposed to add to exit the camera application from my third party application.

Can Someone Please help me understand....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I ended up using, its much better.

```
public class MyScreen extends MainScreen{
Player _p;
VideoControl _videoControl;  
FileConnection fileconn;
String PATH;
String GetfileName;
LabelField GetPhotofileName = new LabelField("",LabelField.FOCUSABLE){
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
        Dialog.alert("Clicked");
    return true;
    }
 };

 public static boolean SdcardAvailabulity() {
     String root = null;
     Enumeration e = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
     while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
         root = (String) e.nextElement();
         if( root.equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard/") ) {
             return true;
         }else if( root.equalsIgnoreCase("store/") ) {
             return false;
         }
     }
     class MySDListener implements FileSystemListener {
         public void rootChanged(int state, String rootName) {
             if( state == ROOT_ADDED ) {
                 if( rootName.equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard/") ) {
                 }
             } else if( state == ROOT_REMOVED ) {
             }
         }
     }
     return true;
 }
 protected boolean invokeAction(int action){
     boolean handled = super.invokeAction(action); 
     if(SdcardAvailabulity()){
           PATH = System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.memorycard.photos")+"Image_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";//here "str" having the current Date and Time;
     } else {
         PATH = System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.photos")+"Image_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg"; 
     }
     if(!handled){
         if(action == ACTION_INVOKE){   
             try{                      
                 byte[] rawImage = _videoControl.getSnapshot(null);
                 fileconn=(FileConnection)Connector.open(PATH);
                 if(fileconn.exists()){
                    fileconn.delete();
                 }
                 fileconn.create();
                 OutputStream os=fileconn.openOutputStream();
                 os.write(rawImage);
                 GetfileName =fileconn.getName();
                 fileconn.close();
                 os.close();
                 Status.show("Image is Captured",200);
                 GetPhotofileName.setText(GetfileName);
                 if(_p!=null)
                    _p.close();          
             }catch(Exception e){
                if(_p!=null){
                    _p.close();
                 }
                 if(fileconn!=null){
                    try{
                         fileconn.close();
                     }catch (IOException e1){ 
                     }
                 }                    
             }
         }
      }           
      return handled;                
  }
 public MyScreen(){
     setTitle("Camera App");
     try{
        _p = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("capture://video?encoding=jpeg&width=1024&height=768");
        _p.realize();
        _videoControl = (VideoControl) _p.getControl("VideoControl");
        if (_videoControl != null){
            Field videoField = (Field) _videoControl.initDisplayMode (VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");
            _videoControl.setDisplayFullScreen(true);
             _videoControl.setVisible(true);
            _p.start();
            if(videoField != null){
                add(videoField);
            }
        } 
     }catch(Exception e){
         if(_p!=null) {
             _p.close();
         }
         Dialog.alert(e.toString());
     }   
     add(GetPhotofileName);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to close the Camera app from your app is tricky.  I don't know of a clean way to do it, but [I have done it this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11030752/119114).

Basically, your app needs to request permission

```
ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INPUT_SIMULATION
```

to inject keystrokes.  It will then simulate the pressing of the **ESC** key, which is how a user would/could close the Camera app manually.  To make this technique more reliable, I need to have the code (conditionally) inject the ESC key multiple times.

The way I make this more reliable is that I have a `Screen` in my app that is showing, **before** I launch the Camera app.  I then monitor that screen to see when it has been *exposed* again.  When I detect that it has been exposed, I assume that I must have injected *enough* ESC key sequences to close the Camera (or I guess the user could have pressed **ESC** themselves, to get back to my app).

**Update:** per comment below, here is some additional code I used in this solution, to detect proper Camera closure by monitoring the *exposed* state of one of my Screens below it:

```
private boolean _isExposed = false;

protected void onExposed() {
    super.onExposed();
    _isExposed = true;
}

protected void onObscured() {
    super.onObscured();
    _isExposed = false;
}

public boolean isExposed() {
    return _isExposed;
}
```

You can also set `_isExposed` to false in whatever method you use to open the Camera app in the first place, if you like.

Comment: Thank you I will give you feedback once I have tried out the method.

Comment: I get an error saying "The method 'isExposed()' is undefined for the type MainScreen" Should I add it into a class where i dont extend MainScreen?

Comment: @Nequita, I updated my answer with the code I added to do this.  `isExposed()` was a method that I added, so that's why you get the compile error.  Please remember to **up vote** and / or **accept** answers that work for you.  Thanks.